# Find the optimal value

Tags: shell, utilities, optimization

Let us say I have a program called `foo`. It takes 1 argument (e.g. `foo 42`) and it spits out a single line containing a numerical value (e.g. `2034`).

I want to find the optimal value for the input argument, so the output is minimized. Currently I do that by hand by (semi-)binary search, but that is slow - especially if `foo` is slow.

Is there an automated tool to find the optimal value for the input?

We assume the values are continuous, and it is OK to find a local optimum, so something that uses gradient descent would be ideal (especially if it can take n inputs).

As an example you can use this for `foo`:

```
perl -e 'print (1+(shift() - 10203040506)**2)'
```

In the example I want the tool to return 10203040506 since it gives the smallest value.

Comment: So essentially, you want to implement a [Newton–Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) method in shell? Would a [perl](https://nanopdf.com/download/newton-raphson-iteration-in-perl-randolph-langley-november-26-2008_pdf) script be acceptable?

Comment: @doneal24 Yes, that looks right, and Perl is OK. (Though I would prefer an existing tool).

Comment: There is (of course) a [perl module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Calculus::NewtonRaphson) that does this. I don't know if it can be adapted to your use case. You are bringing back memories of programming this for quantum chemistry optimizations 40 years ago. :)

Comment: @doneal24 The module uses `differentiate` and my input is not a math expression. So unfortunately no luck.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're looking for; I think I might just be a bit dense here, but could you explicitly state what the "1 argument" is that you pass in, and honestly I don't know what "PRG" is; I know PRNGs (quite intimately by now, actually), but then the requirement makes little sense, unless your PRNG is really bad, and you're looking for the state that makes its output as close to zero as possible. So, I don't understand the input, and what it is that you want to optimize.

Comment: PRG is just th name of the program. Let me change it to `foo` so it is not confused with PRNG (because it has nothing to do with PRNG).

Comment: There is no need to differentiate any function in the Newton-Raphson method. Just needs a way to get values back from the function. But I am sure that [Mathlab should be a good way to implement it](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-s997-introduction-to-matlab-programming-fall-2011/pages/root-finding/newtons-method/). Understand that you are seeking a minimum, no a zero, so the method needs some tweaking.

Comment: Hmmm, yes there is also a [numerical method for Python](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter19.04-Newton-Raphson-Method.html).

Comment: @QuartzCristal The Python method also need computing the derivate (`f_prime`) and since `foo` is not a mathematical function this cannot be done.

Comment: @OleTange this really leaves the scope of Unix/Linux, but: optimization methods often work by using the difference quotient as approximation of the derivative. `scipy.optimize` for example can do that (and does that).

Comment: The actual value of the derivative is just the value of the function at two (nearby x) subtracted and divided by (average) x. In short the slope of the function calculated at two points. I know because I had to implement such that method in college many years back. But finding a minimum gets tricky. I don't recall the specifics from the top of my head right now. Please read https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-eighth-grade-math/cc-8th-linear-equations-functions/8th-slope/a/slope-formula

Comment: And yes, there is no shell method to do that, and I strongly suspect that that doesn't exist. @OleTange

Answer (score 0):

First version is now available: https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/find-optimal

It uses Nelder-Mead and it only works well on floats. It does very bad on integer values.

If you know of a "Nelder-Mead" for integers, let me know - especially if there is sample Python code for it.